# I am using Sticky p:toolbar, when model dialog open sticky tool bar and sticky menu appear on top if we scroll the page

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Sticky p:toolbar, when model dialog open sticky tool bar and sticky menu appear on top and accessible even if model dialog is open when I scroll the page.

[image] scroll page

Please help.

Comment: That the problem of z-index

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should disable backgroud component when p:dialog is open.
Use modal="true" in p:dialog for same. 
See [primeface-5-dialog](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/dialog/basic.xhtml)